# GCC compile error: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat]

Tags: c, gcc, char

Ok, I'm a noob with C, but I think the code is basic and straightforward. This program is for a college assignment, and is supposed to have the 'isdigit()' function in it. Here is the code

```
//by Nyxm
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

main()
{
    char userChar;
    int userNum, randNum;
    srand(clock());
    printf("\nThis program will generate a random number between 0 and 9 for a user to guess.\n");
    /*I changed it from '1 to 10' to '0 to 9' to be able to use the isdigit() function which
    will only let me use a 1 digit character for an argument*/
    printf("Please enter a digit from 0 to 9 as your guess: ");
    scanf("%c", userChar);
    if (isdigit(userChar))
    {
            userNum = userChar - '0';
            randNum = (rand() % 10);
            if (userNum == randNum)
            {
                    printf("Good guess! It was the random number.\n");
            }
            else
            {
                    printf("Sorry, the random number was %d.\n", randNum);
            }
    }
    else
    {
            printf("Sorry, you did not enter a digit between 0 and 9. Please try to run the program again.\$
    }
}
```

When I try to compile, I get the following error

```
week3work1.c: In function ‘main’:
week3work1.c:14:2: warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat]
```

What on earth is going on? I am desperate for help. Any help at all. I am seriously about to just give up on this program. Why is it saying it expects argument of 'char *' when my textbook shows that "%c" is for regular ole 'char'? I am using nano, gcc, and Ubuntu if that makes any difference.

Comment: `gcc` produces multiple warnings for your program.  You should fix *all* of them.  For example, you're missing `#include <stdlib.h>` (required for `srand()` and `rand()`) and `#include <time.h>` (required for `clock()`).

Comment: @KeithThompson When compiling, I no longer have errors, and the program now works as I wanted it to. So, I guess I am asking if it will continue working? Because in my textbook, the only preprocessor statement needed is '#include <stdio.h>' and the '#include <ctype.h>' is for the isdigit() function.

Comment: You need the headers I described above if you're going to call those functions.  There are circumstances in which you can get away without using them, but I won't go into the details; just add the `#include` directives.  gcc will warn about the function calls if you use `-std=c99 -pedantic`.  What textbook are you using?  If it shows an example that calls `rand()` without `#include <stdlib.h>`, or that calls `clock()` without `#include <time.h>`, then your textbook is wrong.

Comment: @KeithThompson The book that I was given is "C Programming for the absolute beginner 2nd Edition" by Michael A. Vine. I have noticed that some of the exercises at the end of each chapter have to do with advanced topics that haven't even come close to be discussed. For example, at the end of the 2nd chapter (on primary data types) one excercise was to create a program that uses scanf() to allow a user to enter their name. Which would be a string, and the chapter had barely covered characters, let alone strings.

Comment: Something I should have mentioned before: `printf` and `scanf` formats are not the same. For `printf`, `%c` requires an argument of type `int`, which should be a character value. For `scanf`, `%c` requires a pointer to `char`. Be sure you're reading the documentation for the function you're using.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For `scanf()`, you need to pass a pointer to a `char`, otherwise it doesn't have any way to store the character, since said `char` would be passed in by value. So you need `&userChar` instead.

Let's say `userChar` is `0` before the call. With your current code, you're basically doing this (as far as utility goes):

```
scanf("%c", 0);
```

What you want is this:

```
scanf("%c", some-location-to-put-a-char);
```

Which is `&userChar`.

The `man` page for `scanf` mentions this:

> ```
>    c      Matches  a  sequence  of characters whose length is specified by
>           the maximum field width (default 1); the next pointer must be  a
>           pointer to char, and there must be enough room for all the char‐
>           acters (no terminating null byte is added).  The usual  skip  of
>           leading  white  space is suppressed.  To skip white space first,
>           use an explicit space in the format.
> ```

Comment: Good grief. I can't believe I forgot the '&'. Man I feel like an idiot. Will comment again directly with results.

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you soooo much. I have been struggling with this program for a few days now. First it was the char to int conversion, and now this. Once again, thanks!

Comment: +1 great way of explaining pass by value with an actual expansion of the value.

Answer (score 1):

replace `scanf("%c", userChar);` with `scanf("%c", &userChar);`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in a pointer instead of the value of the char.

```
scanf("%c",&userChar);
```